# Developer notification apps

Tags: monitoring, iphone-app, notification

I'm looking for an application that can help me monitor my server and application and can update me of any problems, preferably with an application for my iPhone so it can send me push notifications. Support for my Apple watch (complications) would be wonderful but is not required.

Since a lot of services integrate with Slack I was thinking about setting this up, but since I'm an independent developer and most of the time work alone isn't this the right solution, since it was meant as group communication app.

Some examples about notifications:

- Give me updates about CI or Push to deploy status (For example: Push to deploy fails)
- Problems with VPS
- Failed ping test (updown.io for example)
- Integration with something like bugsnag
- Maybe even an api if my application fails,...

A lot of services do support slack for notifications, but since I'm alone this might not be the best solution.

Comment: Not a developer here - the closest thing I know of is [Catlight](https://catlight.io/). Though it doesn't have iPhone nor Apple Watch support.